# ASP.NET membership tables for ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I have a ASP.NET application running on the server using ASP.NET membership provider. I would like to use the same database for my ASP.NET MVC3 application.

Do I only need to change the connection string in the Web.Config file? I tried that but no luck.

Comment: What version of the .NET framework this existing ASP.NET application has been created with? What didn't work when you change the connection string? Error message?

Comment: Are you not able to login or are you getting some other error?  Ensure you have the MVC app's web.config set correctly, too (<authentication mode="Forms">...</authentication>, etc).

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov I would have provide you more details but now I am facing an strange problem. I have mentioned the same in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080192/error-while-running-mvc3-application

Comment: @jdangelo Could you help me out with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080192/error-while-running-mvc3-application so that I can run the application and provide you the exact error message.

Comment: now that your other problem is solved, did it fix this one?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how is implemented your  membership provider.
You might have to create your own implementation of memmbership provider for the both applications to share the same data tables.

check this guide how to do this:
http://www.danharman.net/2011/06/23/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection/