# Error while running MVC3 Application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

i have Visual Studio 2010.

Recently I was using MVC2 and due to some reason I installed MVC3 in my computer. Everything was working fine, till today.

Now when I am creating new project, I am getting below error:
[image][image]

**When I clicked on debug**[image]

**When I went to the folder and tried to open the solution I am getting this**

[image][image]

Please help

**EDIT 1**

When I open the C# project file of the application and tried to run I am getting the below error[image]

Also when I added a controller and tried to right click on the method to create view. I am not getting any option of "Add View"[image]

**I suspect the problem is due to any corrupt DLL or assembly.**

**Edit**

Linked to another question [Error while running MVC3 Application after reinstalling also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168185/error-while-running-mvc3-application-after-reinstalling-also)

Comment: **Note** I am able to create/run/execute new/old MVC2 projects. But not for MVC3 application. Till yesterday MVC3 application was working fine too.

Comment: Did you install anything between it working and this? (Starting simple and definitely don't mean this as an insult)

Comment: @jdangelo No, I didn't install anything. It was working fine till yesterday night. And also I don't feel offended when someone try to help me. Thanks for your comments :-)

Comment: hmmm, I wonder if the MVC3 binaries became corrupted somehow.  Have you tried uninstalling MVC3 and MVC3-Visual Studio Tools and reinstalling them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try uninstalling and then reinstalling the MVC3 binaries in Add/Remove Programs.  Be sure to grab both the MVC 3 and MVC 3 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools.

Note: I am saying the Tools as well because VS crashed on you when you tried to create a new application.