# Error while running MVC3 Application after reinstalling also

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, installation

My issue still persist. Reference to the thread [Error while running MVC3 Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080192/error-while-running-mvc3-application)

Though I marked it as an answer as **it did resolved my issue after *reinstalling MVC3*** but after **8** days this issue reappears but this time every single effort is failed:

I installed MVC 3 after uninstalling it:

- I installed MVC 3 by Web Installer.
- http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d2928bc1-f48c-4e95-a064-2a455a22c8f6
- Than
  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=82cbd599-d29a-43e3-b78b-0f863d22811a&displaylang=en

but the same error is displayed. Any suggestion ?

Please help.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Could you please help me ?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the error log it generates to see if there's anything useful in it? Another thing, do you know if you have VS2010SP1 installed? Was it installed prior to the MVC3 tools update or after? I'm just spitballing for different scenarios.

Comment: @Khepri This is an absolute fine suggestion. I have checked into the error report and it is something wierd to understand (I mean plety of hex code, lots of dll names and lots of process names). I tried to take the screen shot of it for your reference but it dosen't seems to present the full descritpion.

Comment: @Khepri I haven't installed VS2010 ever before, all I did was the installation of VS2010. It comes with MVC 1 & MVC 2. Than, when I installed MVC 3, I created and run few simple website project. Everything worked fine for 10-15 days than I ran into the error while creating new project and running the old one.

Comment: Can you go to Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio and check the version? It should say 10.0.40219.1 SP1 Rel if you have the service pack installed. Again, this is absolute guess work. If you don't have the SP installed (and the logs don't have anything useful) I'd start by removing the MVC3 tools update, applying 2010SP1, and then reinstalling the MVC3 tools update. If you do have the SP installed, I'm really at a loss and will refrain from making a suggestion on this route unless absolutely necessary. :-)

Comment: @Khepri Thanks again. Let me try that with SP1 and I will get back to this question.

Comment: @Khepri  That resolved my issue. Could you please move your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Heh, let's wait a bit to make sure it holds together. I saw the last time this happened to you the problem reoccurred a week or so later. :-) I'll drop by this thread in a week and check in.

Comment: @Khepri I appreciate your proffessionalism. Even though I request you to shift it as an answer because just in case if you missed this thread I will be able to select you comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you go to Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio and check the version? It should say 10.0.40219.1 SP1 Rel if you have the service pack installed. Again, this is absolute guess work. If you don't have the SP installed (and the logs don't have anything useful) I'd start by removing the MVC3 tools update, applying 2010SP1, and then reinstalling the MVC3 tools update. If you do have the SP installed, I'm really at a loss and will refrain from making a suggestion on this route unless absolutely necessary. :-)

Comment: Hope everything is still holding together. :-)